# RTC Alarm deepSleep STM32L073RZ

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, low-power, sleep, nucleo

I'm trying to configure 2 differents Alarms on my STM32L073RZ to leave the deepSleep mode but unfortunately after the first wakeUp the memory is reset and the second alarm never wakeUp the STM32. My first alarm is 30seconds after the power On of the board and the second 2 minutes after the power on. But actually the card wakeUp every 30 seconds. 
This is my script (From the STMicroelectronics web site)

```
/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "main.h"


/* RTC handler declaration */
RTC_HandleTypeDef RTCHandle;


/* Buffer used for displaying Time */
uint8_t aShowTime[50] = {0};
static __IO uint32_t TimingDelay;

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void SystemPower_Config(void);
static void Error_Handler(void);
static void RTC_AlarmConfig(void);
static void RTC_TimeShow(uint8_t* showtime);

/* Private functions ---------------------------------------------------------*/

/**
  * @brief  Main program
  * @param  None
  * @retval None
  */
int main(void)
{
  /* STM32L0xx HAL library initialization:
       - Configure the Flash prefetch, Flash preread and Buffer caches
       - Systick timer is configured by default as source of time base, but user 
             can eventually implement his proper time base source (a general purpose 
             timer for example or other time source), keeping in mind that Time base 
             duration should be kept 1ms since PPP_TIMEOUT_VALUEs are defined and 
             handled in milliseconds basis.
       - Low Level Initialization
     */
  HAL_Init();

  /* Configure the system clock to 2 MHz */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* Configure LED2 */
  BSP_LED_Init(LED2);

  RTCHandle.Instance = RTC;

  /* Configure RTC prescaler and RTC data registers */
  /* RTC configured as follows:
      - Hour Format    = Format 24
      - Asynch Prediv  = Value according to source clock
      - Synch Prediv   = Value according to source clock
      - OutPut         = Output Disable
      - OutPutPolarity = High Polarity
      - OutPutType     = Open Drain */
  RTCHandle.Init.HourFormat     = RTC_HOURFORMAT_24;
  RTCHandle.Init.AsynchPrediv   = RTC_ASYNCH_PREDIV;
  RTCHandle.Init.SynchPrediv    = RTC_SYNCH_PREDIV;
  RTCHandle.Init.OutPut         = RTC_OUTPUT_DISABLE;
  RTCHandle.Init.OutPutPolarity = RTC_OUTPUT_POLARITY_HIGH;
  RTCHandle.Init.OutPutType     = RTC_OUTPUT_TYPE_OPENDRAIN;
  if (HAL_RTC_Init(&RTCHandle) != HAL_OK)
  {
    /* Initialization Error */
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /*##-2- Configure Alarm ####################################################*/
  /* Configure RTC Alarm */
  RTC_AlarmConfig();

  /* Configure the system Power */
  SystemPower_Config();

  /* Check and handle if the system was resumed from StandBy mode */ 
  if(__HAL_PWR_GET_FLAG(PWR_FLAG_SB) != RESET)
  {
    /* Clear Standby flag */
    __HAL_PWR_CLEAR_FLAG(PWR_FLAG_SB); 
  }

  /* Insert 5 seconds delay */
  HAL_Delay(5000);

  /* The Following Wakeup sequence is highly recommended prior to each Standby mode entry
    mainly  when using more than one wakeup source this is to not miss any wakeup event.
    - Disable all used wakeup sources,
    - Clear all related wakeup flags, 
    - Re-enable all used wakeup sources,
    - Enter the Standby mode.
  */
  /* Disable all used wakeup sources*/
  HAL_RTCEx_DeactivateWakeUpTimer(&RTCHandle);

  /* Re-enable all used wakeup sources*/
  /* ## Setting the Wake up time ############################################*/
  /*  RTC Wakeup Interrupt Generation:
    Wakeup Time Base = (RTC_WAKEUPCLOCK_RTCCLK_DIV /(LSI))
    Wakeup Time = Wakeup Time Base * WakeUpCounter
      = (RTC_WAKEUPCLOCK_RTCCLK_DIV /(LSI)) * WakeUpCounter
      ==> WakeUpCounter = Wakeup Time / Wakeup Time Base

    To configure the wake up timer to 4s the WakeUpCounter is set to 0x1FFF:
    RTC_WAKEUPCLOCK_RTCCLK_DIV = RTCCLK_Div16 = 16
    Wakeup Time Base = 16 /(~39.000KHz) = ~0,410 ms
    Wakeup Time = ~4s = 0,410ms  * WakeUpCounter
      ==> WakeUpCounter = ~4s/0,410ms = 9750 = 0x2616 */
  //HAL_RTCEx_SetWakeUpTimer_IT(&RTCHandle, 0x14, RTC_WAKEUPCLOCK_CK_SPRE_16BITS);


  /* Clear all related wakeup flags */
  __HAL_PWR_CLEAR_FLAG(PWR_FLAG_WU);

  /* Enter the Standby mode */
  HAL_PWR_EnterSTANDBYMode();

  while (1)
  {
  }
}

/**
  * @brief  System Clock Configuration
  *         The system Clock is configured as follow : 
  *            System Clock source            = MSI
  *            SYSCLK(Hz)                     = 2000000
  *            HCLK(Hz)                       = 2000000
  *            AHB Prescaler                  = 1
  *            APB1 Prescaler                 = 1
  *            APB2 Prescaler                 = 1
  *            Flash Latency(WS)              = 0
  *            Main regulator output voltage  = Scale3 mode
  * @retval None
  */
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};

  /* Enable MSI Oscillator */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_MSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.MSIState = RCC_MSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.MSIClockRange = RCC_MSIRANGE_5;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.MSICalibrationValue=0x00;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_NONE;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct)!= HAL_OK)
  {
    /* Initialization Error */
    while(1); 
  }

  /* Select MSI as system clock source and configure the HCLK, PCLK1 and PCLK2 
     clocks dividers */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = (RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK | RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK | RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1 | RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2);
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_MSI;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;  
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;  
  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_0)!= HAL_OK)
  {
    /* Initialization Error */
    while(1); 
  }
  /* Enable Power Control clock */
  __HAL_RCC_PWR_CLK_ENABLE();

  /* The voltage scaling allows optimizing the power consumption when the device is 
     clocked below the maximum system frequency, to update the voltage scaling value 
     regarding system frequency refer to product datasheet.  */
  __HAL_PWR_VOLTAGESCALING_CONFIG(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE3);

  /* Disable Power Control clock */
  __HAL_RCC_PWR_CLK_DISABLE();

}


/**
  * @brief  System Power Configuration
  *         The system Power is configured as follow :
  *            + RTC Clocked by LSI
  *            + VREFINT OFF, with fast wakeup enabled
  *            + No IWDG
  *            + Automatic Wakeup using RTC clocked by LSI (after ~4s)
  * @param  None
  * @retval None
  */
static void SystemPower_Config(void)
{
  /* Enable Power Control clock */
  __HAL_RCC_PWR_CLK_ENABLE();

  HAL_PWREx_EnableUltraLowPower();

  /* Enable the fast wake up from Ultra low power mode */
  HAL_PWREx_EnableFastWakeUp();

  /* Configure RTC */
  RTCHandle.Instance = RTC;
  /* Set the RTC time base to 1s */
  /* Configure RTC prescaler and RTC data registers as follow:
    - Hour Format = Format 24
    - Asynch Prediv = Value according to source clock
    - Synch Prediv = Value according to source clock
    - OutPut = Output Disable
    - OutPutPolarity = High Polarity
    - OutPutType = Open Drain */
  RTCHandle.Init.HourFormat = RTC_HOURFORMAT_24;
  RTCHandle.Init.AsynchPrediv = RTC_ASYNCH_PREDIV;
  RTCHandle.Init.SynchPrediv = RTC_SYNCH_PREDIV;
  RTCHandle.Init.OutPut = RTC_OUTPUT_DISABLE;
  RTCHandle.Init.OutPutPolarity = RTC_OUTPUT_POLARITY_HIGH;
  RTCHandle.Init.OutPutType = RTC_OUTPUT_TYPE_OPENDRAIN;
  if(HAL_RTC_Init(&RTCHandle) != HAL_OK)
  {
    /* Initialization Error */
    Error_Handler(); 
  }
}


/**
  * @brief  This function is executed in case of error occurrence.
  * @param  None
  * @retval None
  */
static void Error_Handler(void)
{
  /* Turn on the LED2 */
  BSP_LED_On(LED2);
  while(1)
  {
  }
}

#ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT

/**
  * @brief  Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
  *         where the assert_param error has occurred.
  * @param  file: pointer to the source file name
  * @param  line: assert_param error line source number
  * @retval None
  */
void assert_failed(uint8_t *file, uint32_t line)
{
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
     ex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */

  /* Infinite loop */
  while (1)
  {
  }
}
#endif

/**
  * @brief  Alarm callback
  * @param  hrtc : RTC handle
  * @retval None
  */
void HAL_RTC_AlarmAEventCallback(RTC_HandleTypeDef *hrtc)
{
  /* Turn LED2 on: Alarm generation */
  BSP_LED_On(LED2);
}

/**
  * @brief  Configure the current time and date.
  * @param  None
  * @retval None
  */
static void RTC_AlarmConfig(void)
{
  RTC_DateTypeDef  sdatestructure;
  RTC_TimeTypeDef  stimestructure;
  RTC_AlarmTypeDef salarmstructure;
  RTC_AlarmTypeDef salarmstructure2;

  /*##-1- Configure the Date #################################################*/
  /* Set Date: Tuesday February 18th 2014 */
  sdatestructure.Year = 0x14;
  sdatestructure.Month = RTC_MONTH_FEBRUARY;
  sdatestructure.Date = 0x18;
  sdatestructure.WeekDay = RTC_WEEKDAY_TUESDAY;

  if(HAL_RTC_SetDate(&RTCHandle,&sdatestructure,RTC_FORMAT_BCD) != HAL_OK)
  {
    /* Initialization Error */
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /*##-2- Configure the Time #################################################*/
  /* Set Time: 02:20:00 */
  stimestructure.Hours = 0x02;
  stimestructure.Minutes = 0x20;
  stimestructure.Seconds = 0x00;
  stimestructure.TimeFormat = RTC_HOURFORMAT12_AM;
  stimestructure.DayLightSaving = RTC_DAYLIGHTSAVING_NONE ;
  stimestructure.StoreOperation = RTC_STOREOPERATION_RESET;

  if(HAL_RTC_SetTime(&RTCHandle,&stimestructure,RTC_FORMAT_BCD) != HAL_OK)
  {
    /* Initialization Error */
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /*##-3- Configure the RTC Alarm peripheral #################################*/
  /* Set Alarm to 02:20:30
     RTC Alarm Generation: Alarm on Hours, Minutes and Seconds */
  salarmstructure.Alarm = RTC_ALARM_A;
  salarmstructure.AlarmDateWeekDay = RTC_WEEKDAY_MONDAY;
  salarmstructure.AlarmDateWeekDaySel = RTC_ALARMDATEWEEKDAYSEL_WEEKDAY;
  salarmstructure.AlarmMask = RTC_ALARMMASK_DATEWEEKDAY;
  salarmstructure.AlarmSubSecondMask = RTC_ALARMSUBSECONDMASK_NONE;
  salarmstructure.AlarmTime.TimeFormat = RTC_HOURFORMAT12_AM;
  salarmstructure.AlarmTime.Hours = 0x02;
  salarmstructure.AlarmTime.Minutes = 0x22;
  salarmstructure.AlarmTime.Seconds = 0x00;
  salarmstructure.AlarmTime.SubSeconds = 0x56;


  salarmstructure2.Alarm = RTC_ALARM_B;
  salarmstructure2.AlarmDateWeekDay = RTC_WEEKDAY_MONDAY;
  salarmstructure2.AlarmDateWeekDaySel = RTC_ALARMDATEWEEKDAYSEL_WEEKDAY;
  salarmstructure2.AlarmMask = RTC_ALARMMASK_DATEWEEKDAY;
  salarmstructure2.AlarmSubSecondMask = RTC_ALARMSUBSECONDMASK_NONE;
  salarmstructure2.AlarmTime.TimeFormat = RTC_HOURFORMAT12_AM;
  salarmstructure2.AlarmTime.Hours = 0x02;
  salarmstructure2.AlarmTime.Minutes = 0x20;
  salarmstructure2.AlarmTime.Seconds = 0x30;
  salarmstructure2.AlarmTime.SubSeconds = 0x56;



  if(HAL_RTC_SetAlarm_IT(&RTCHandle,&salarmstructure,RTC_FORMAT_BCD) != HAL_OK)
  {
    /* Initialization Error */
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if(HAL_RTC_SetAlarm_IT(&RTCHandle,&salarmstructure2,RTC_FORMAT_BCD) != HAL_OK)
  {
    /* Initialization Error */
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

/**
  * @brief  Display the current time.
  * @param  showtime : pointer to buffer
  * @retval None
  */
static void RTC_TimeShow(uint8_t* showtime)
{
  RTC_DateTypeDef sdatestructureget;
  RTC_TimeTypeDef stimestructureget;

  /* Get the RTC current Time */
  HAL_RTC_GetTime(&RTCHandle, &stimestructureget, RTC_FORMAT_BIN);
  /* Get the RTC current Date */
  HAL_RTC_GetDate(&RTCHandle, &sdatestructureget, RTC_FORMAT_BIN);
  /* Display time Format : hh:mm:ss */
  sprintf((char*)showtime,"%02d:%02d:%02d",stimestructureget.Hours, stimestructureget.Minutes, stimestructureget.Seconds);
}

#ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT

/**
  * @brief  Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
  *         where the assert_param error has occurred.
  * @param  file: pointer to the source file name
  * @param  line: assert_param error line source number
  * @retval None
  */
void assert_failed(uint8_t *file, uint32_t line)
{
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
     ex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */

  /* Infinite loop */
  while (1)
  {
  }
}
#endif
```

EDIT:

This is my new script with the LED and the "PWR_FLAG_WU". The LED still OFF during all the process

```
#include "main.h"

/** @addtogroup STM32L0xx_HAL_Examples
  * @{
  */

/** @addtogroup PWR_STANDBY_RTC
  * @{
  */

/* Private typedef -----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Private define ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Private macro -------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/* RTC handler declaration */
RTC_HandleTypeDef RTCHandle;


/* Buffer used for displaying Time */
uint8_t aShowTime[50] = {0};
static __IO uint32_t TimingDelay;

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void SystemPower_Config(void);
static void Error_Handler(void);
static void RTC_AlarmConfig(void);
static void RTC_TimeShow(uint8_t* showtime);

/* Private functions ---------------------------------------------------------*/

/**
  * @brief  Main program
  * @param  None
  * @retval None
  */
int main(void)
{
  /* STM32L0xx HAL library initialization:
       - Configure the Flash prefetch, Flash preread and Buffer caches
       - Systick timer is configured by default as source of time base, but user 
             can eventually implement his proper time base source (a general purpose 
             timer for example or other time source), keeping in mind that Time base 
             duration should be kept 1ms since PPP_TIMEOUT_VALUEs are defined and 
             handled in milliseconds basis.
       - Low Level Initialization
     */
  HAL_Init();

  /* Configure the system clock to 2 MHz */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* Configure LED2 */
  BSP_LED_Init(LED2);

  RTCHandle.Instance = RTC;

  /* Configure RTC prescaler and RTC data registers */
  /* RTC configured as follows:
      - Hour Format    = Format 24
      - Asynch Prediv  = Value according to source clock
      - Synch Prediv   = Value according to source clock
      - OutPut         = Output Disable
      - OutPutPolarity = High Polarity
      - OutPutType     = Open Drain */
  RTCHandle.Init.HourFormat     = RTC_HOURFORMAT_24;
  RTCHandle.Init.AsynchPrediv   = RTC_ASYNCH_PREDIV;
  RTCHandle.Init.SynchPrediv    = RTC_SYNCH_PREDIV;
  RTCHandle.Init.OutPut         = RTC_OUTPUT_DISABLE;
  RTCHandle.Init.OutPutPolarity = RTC_OUTPUT_POLARITY_HIGH;
  RTCHandle.Init.OutPutType     = RTC_OUTPUT_TYPE_OPENDRAIN;
  if (HAL_RTC_Init(&RTCHandle) != HAL_OK)
  {
    /* Initialization Error */
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /*##-2- Configure Alarm ####################################################*/
  /* Configure RTC Alarm */
  RTC_AlarmConfig();

  /* Configure the system Power */
  SystemPower_Config();

  /* Check and handle if the system was resumed from StandBy mode */ 
  if(__HAL_PWR_GET_FLAG(PWR_FLAG_WU) != RESET)
  {
    /* Clear Standby flag */
    __HAL_PWR_CLEAR_FLAG(PWR_FLAG_WU);
  }
  else
  {
    RTC_AlarmConfig();
    BSP_LED_On(LED2);
  }

  /* Insert 5 seconds delay */
  HAL_Delay(5000);

  /* The Following Wakeup sequence is highly recommended prior to each Standby mode entry
    mainly  when using more than one wakeup source this is to not miss any wakeup event.
    - Disable all used wakeup sources,
    - Clear all related wakeup flags, 
    - Re-enable all used wakeup sources,
    - Enter the Standby mode.
  */
  /* Disable all used wakeup sources*/
  HAL_RTCEx_DeactivateWakeUpTimer(&RTCHandle);

  /* Re-enable all used wakeup sources*/
  /* ## Setting the Wake up time ############################################*/
  /*  RTC Wakeup Interrupt Generation:
    Wakeup Time Base = (RTC_WAKEUPCLOCK_RTCCLK_DIV /(LSI))
    Wakeup Time = Wakeup Time Base * WakeUpCounter
      = (RTC_WAKEUPCLOCK_RTCCLK_DIV /(LSI)) * WakeUpCounter
      ==> WakeUpCounter = Wakeup Time / Wakeup Time Base

    To configure the wake up timer to 4s the WakeUpCounter is set to 0x1FFF:
    RTC_WAKEUPCLOCK_RTCCLK_DIV = RTCCLK_Div16 = 16
    Wakeup Time Base = 16 /(~39.000KHz) = ~0,410 ms
    Wakeup Time = ~4s = 0,410ms  * WakeUpCounter
      ==> WakeUpCounter = ~4s/0,410ms = 9750 = 0x2616 */
  //HAL_RTCEx_SetWakeUpTimer_IT(&RTCHandle, 0x14, RTC_WAKEUPCLOCK_CK_SPRE_16BITS);


  /* Clear all related wakeup flags */
  __HAL_PWR_CLEAR_FLAG(PWR_FLAG_WU);

  /* Enter the Standby mode */
  HAL_PWR_EnterSTANDBYMode();

  while (1)
  {
  }
}

/**
  * @brief  System Clock Configuration
  *         The system Clock is configured as follow : 
  *            System Clock source            = MSI
  *            SYSCLK(Hz)                     = 2000000
  *            HCLK(Hz)                       = 2000000
  *            AHB Prescaler                  = 1
  *            APB1 Prescaler                 = 1
  *            APB2 Prescaler                 = 1
  *            Flash Latency(WS)              = 0
  *            Main regulator output voltage  = Scale3 mode
  * @retval None
  */
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};

  /* Enable MSI Oscillator */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_MSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.MSIState = RCC_MSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.MSIClockRange = RCC_MSIRANGE_5;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.MSICalibrationValue=0x00;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_NONE;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct)!= HAL_OK)
  {
    /* Initialization Error */
    while(1); 
  }

  /* Select MSI as system clock source and configure the HCLK, PCLK1 and PCLK2 
     clocks dividers */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = (RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK | RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK | RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1 | RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2);
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_MSI;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;  
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;  
  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_0)!= HAL_OK)
  {
    /* Initialization Error */
    while(1); 
  }
  /* Enable Power Control clock */
  __HAL_RCC_PWR_CLK_ENABLE();

  /* The voltage scaling allows optimizing the power consumption when the device is 
     clocked below the maximum system frequency, to update the voltage scaling value 
     regarding system frequency refer to product datasheet.  */
  __HAL_PWR_VOLTAGESCALING_CONFIG(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE3);

  /* Disable Power Control clock */
  __HAL_RCC_PWR_CLK_DISABLE();

}


/**
  * @brief  System Power Configuration
  *         The system Power is configured as follow :
  *            + RTC Clocked by LSI
  *            + VREFINT OFF, with fast wakeup enabled
  *            + No IWDG
  *            + Automatic Wakeup using RTC clocked by LSI (after ~4s)
  * @param  None
  * @retval None
  */
static void SystemPower_Config(void)
{
  /* Enable Power Control clock */
  __HAL_RCC_PWR_CLK_ENABLE();

  HAL_PWREx_EnableUltraLowPower();

  /* Enable the fast wake up from Ultra low power mode */
  HAL_PWREx_EnableFastWakeUp();

  /* Configure RTC */
  RTCHandle.Instance = RTC;
  /* Set the RTC time base to 1s */
  /* Configure RTC prescaler and RTC data registers as follow:
    - Hour Format = Format 24
    - Asynch Prediv = Value according to source clock
    - Synch Prediv = Value according to source clock
    - OutPut = Output Disable
    - OutPutPolarity = High Polarity
    - OutPutType = Open Drain */
  RTCHandle.Init.HourFormat = RTC_HOURFORMAT_24;
  RTCHandle.Init.AsynchPrediv = RTC_ASYNCH_PREDIV;
  RTCHandle.Init.SynchPrediv = RTC_SYNCH_PREDIV;
  RTCHandle.Init.OutPut = RTC_OUTPUT_DISABLE;
  RTCHandle.Init.OutPutPolarity = RTC_OUTPUT_POLARITY_HIGH;
  RTCHandle.Init.OutPutType = RTC_OUTPUT_TYPE_OPENDRAIN;
  if(HAL_RTC_Init(&RTCHandle) != HAL_OK)
  {
    /* Initialization Error */
    Error_Handler(); 
  }
}


/**
  * @brief  This function is executed in case of error occurrence.
  * @param  None
  * @retval None
  */
static void Error_Handler(void)
{
  /* Turn on the LED2 */
  BSP_LED_On(LED2);
  while(1)
  {
  }
}

#ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT

/**
  * @brief  Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
  *         where the assert_param error has occurred.
  * @param  file: pointer to the source file name
  * @param  line: assert_param error line source number
  * @retval None
  */
void assert_failed(uint8_t *file, uint32_t line)
{
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
     ex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */

  /* Infinite loop */
  while (1)
  {
  }
}
#endif

/**
  * @brief  Alarm callback
  * @param  hrtc : RTC handle
  * @retval None
  */
void HAL_RTC_AlarmAEventCallback(RTC_HandleTypeDef *hrtc)
{
  /* Turn LED2 on: Alarm generation */
  BSP_LED_On(LED2);
}

/**
  * @brief  Configure the current time and date.
  * @param  None
  * @retval None
  */
static void RTC_AlarmConfig(void)
{
  RTC_DateTypeDef  sdatestructure;
  RTC_TimeTypeDef  stimestructure;
  RTC_AlarmTypeDef salarmstructure;
  RTC_AlarmTypeDef salarmstructure2;

  /*##-1- Configure the Date #################################################*/
  /* Set Date: Tuesday February 18th 2014 */
  sdatestructure.Year = 0x14;
  sdatestructure.Month = RTC_MONTH_FEBRUARY;
  sdatestructure.Date = 0x18;
  sdatestructure.WeekDay = RTC_WEEKDAY_TUESDAY;

  if(HAL_RTC_SetDate(&RTCHandle,&sdatestructure,RTC_FORMAT_BCD) != HAL_OK)
  {
    /* Initialization Error */
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /*##-2- Configure the Time #################################################*/
  /* Set Time: 02:20:00 */
  stimestructure.Hours = 0x02;
  stimestructure.Minutes = 0x20;
  stimestructure.Seconds = 0x00;
  stimestructure.TimeFormat = RTC_HOURFORMAT12_AM;
  stimestructure.DayLightSaving = RTC_DAYLIGHTSAVING_NONE ;
  stimestructure.StoreOperation = RTC_STOREOPERATION_RESET;

  if(HAL_RTC_SetTime(&RTCHandle,&stimestructure,RTC_FORMAT_BCD) != HAL_OK)
  {
    /* Initialization Error */
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /*##-3- Configure the RTC Alarm peripheral #################################*/
  /* Set Alarm to 02:20:30
     RTC Alarm Generation: Alarm on Hours, Minutes and Seconds */
  salarmstructure.Alarm = RTC_ALARM_A;
  salarmstructure.AlarmDateWeekDay = RTC_WEEKDAY_MONDAY;
  salarmstructure.AlarmDateWeekDaySel = RTC_ALARMDATEWEEKDAYSEL_WEEKDAY;
  salarmstructure.AlarmMask = RTC_ALARMMASK_DATEWEEKDAY;
  salarmstructure.AlarmSubSecondMask = RTC_ALARMSUBSECONDMASK_NONE;
  salarmstructure.AlarmTime.TimeFormat = RTC_HOURFORMAT12_AM;
  salarmstructure.AlarmTime.Hours = 0x02;
  salarmstructure.AlarmTime.Minutes = 0x22;
  salarmstructure.AlarmTime.Seconds = 0x00;
  salarmstructure.AlarmTime.SubSeconds = 0x56;


  salarmstructure2.Alarm = RTC_ALARM_B;
  salarmstructure2.AlarmDateWeekDay = RTC_WEEKDAY_MONDAY;
  salarmstructure2.AlarmDateWeekDaySel = RTC_ALARMDATEWEEKDAYSEL_WEEKDAY;
  salarmstructure2.AlarmMask = RTC_ALARMMASK_DATEWEEKDAY;
  salarmstructure2.AlarmSubSecondMask = RTC_ALARMSUBSECONDMASK_NONE;
  salarmstructure2.AlarmTime.TimeFormat = RTC_HOURFORMAT12_AM;
  salarmstructure2.AlarmTime.Hours = 0x02;
  salarmstructure2.AlarmTime.Minutes = 0x20;
  salarmstructure2.AlarmTime.Seconds = 0x30;
  salarmstructure2.AlarmTime.SubSeconds = 0x56;



  if(HAL_RTC_SetAlarm_IT(&RTCHandle,&salarmstructure,RTC_FORMAT_BCD) != HAL_OK)
  {
    /* Initialization Error */
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if(HAL_RTC_SetAlarm_IT(&RTCHandle,&salarmstructure2,RTC_FORMAT_BCD) != HAL_OK)
  {
    /* Initialization Error */
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

/**
  * @brief  Display the current time.
  * @param  showtime : pointer to buffer
  * @retval None
  */
static void RTC_TimeShow(uint8_t* showtime)
{
  RTC_DateTypeDef sdatestructureget;
  RTC_TimeTypeDef stimestructureget;

  /* Get the RTC current Time */
  HAL_RTC_GetTime(&RTCHandle, &stimestructureget, RTC_FORMAT_BIN);
  /* Get the RTC current Date */
  HAL_RTC_GetDate(&RTCHandle, &sdatestructureget, RTC_FORMAT_BIN);
  /* Display time Format : hh:mm:ss */
  sprintf((char*)showtime,"%02d:%02d:%02d",stimestructureget.Hours, stimestructureget.Minutes, stimestructureget.Seconds);
}

#ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT

/**
  * @brief  Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
  *         where the assert_param error has occurred.
  * @param  file: pointer to the source file name
  * @param  line: assert_param error line source number
  * @retval None
  */
void assert_failed(uint8_t *file, uint32_t line)
{
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
     ex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */

  /* Infinite loop */
  while (1)
  {
  }
}
#endif
```

Comment: Where do you re-enable the wakeup sources before entering standby-mode?

Comment: Humm, maybe this is the problem. I'm a begineer with STM32 and indeed when I look my script I don't see anything to re-enable the wakeup source. What do I do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your code. The RTC registers are part of the backup-domain, and this part is not reseted during Standby mode. From [reference manual](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/2f/b9/c6/34/28/29/42/d2/DM00095744.pdf/files/DM00095744.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00095744.pdf).

> SRAM and register contents are lost except for the RTC registers,
>   RTC backup registers and Standby circuitry

It is you who resets the RTC config. On wakeup, the code will be executed from the begining of the main, where you reconfigure the RTC and the alarms. So the time will be set back to

```
stimestructure.Hours = 0x02;
stimestructure.Minutes = 0x20;
stimestructure.Seconds = 0x00;
```

and the alarms will be reset as well to

Alarm A:

```
salarmstructure.AlarmTime.Hours = 0x02;
salarmstructure.AlarmTime.Minutes = 0x22;
salarmstructure.AlarmTime.Seconds = 0x00;
salarmstructure.AlarmTime.SubSeconds = 0x56;
```

Alarm B:

```
salarmstructure2.AlarmTime.Hours = 0x02;
salarmstructure2.AlarmTime.Minutes = 0x20;
salarmstructure2.AlarmTime.Seconds = 0x30;
salarmstructure2.AlarmTime.SubSeconds = 0x56;
```

**So again the 30 sec alarm (Alarm B) will be fired**.

Now you already have the solution in your code:

```
/* Check and handle if the system was resumed from StandBy mode */ 
if(__HAL_PWR_GET_FLAG(PWR_FLAG_SB) != RESET)
{
  /* Clear Standby flag */
  __HAL_PWR_CLEAR_FLAG(PWR_FLAG_SB); 
}
```

You should configure the RTC time and alarm only if the MCU does not come from Standby mode.
Something like:

```
/* Check and handle if the system was resumed from StandBy mode */ 
if(__HAL_PWR_GET_FLAG(PWR_FLAG_SB) != RESET)
{
  /* Clear Standby flag */
  __HAL_PWR_CLEAR_FLAG(PWR_FLAG_SB); 
}
else
{
  RTC_AlarmConfig();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response. I tried your solution but the problem is the same. I will put below my new script. Can I use USB alimentation or I need to use the E5V with an external power source ? 
Again thank you for your time and attention.

Comment: It is not a forum, only solutions should be posted as answers. Edit your question and update your code instead.

Comment: @SimonNOWAK Hmm, then instead of the `PWR_FLAG_SB` try with `PWR_FLAG_WU`

Comment: and please turn on a LED in the `else` branch to see which branch is really executed

Comment: As you can see, I update the script but the problem still the same. I tried a lot of things but nothing, after 30 seconds my STM32 is reseted.

Comment: @Simon NOWAK - I see and I am thinking on the problem.

Comment: So the LED never switched on but the STM32 always wakes up after 30 sec?

Comment: Yes, the LED never turn ON and my STM32 reset his memory each 30 seconds. The script never go in the else branch. On each cycle my STM32 go in Standby mode.

Comment: Hi, 
I finally found the problem, it come from the flag. To solve that I just change it with another one and put my configureAlarm() in the else branch. Now the program look great, I juste have a little problem, only one of my two Alarm (AlarmA and AlamrB) work. And I try to use serial port but I think this is very hard in this kind of big project. Thank you very much for your help and your time. 

Regards

Simon NOWAK

Comment: Which flag you changed it to?

Comment: I create a new "if" condition under the first one instead of "else" branch. I have made something like that:   if(__HAL_PWR_GET_FLAG(PWR_FLAG_SB) != RESET)
  {
    /* Clear Standby flag */
    __HAL_PWR_CLEAR_FLAG(PWR_FLAG_SB);
  }
  if(__HAL_PWR_GET_FLAG(PWR_FLAG_WU) != SET)
  {
   RTC_AlarmConfig();
  }